# How to make this expected value symbol?

Tags: symbols

I'd like to know how to make in mathmode this fat 'E' as a symbol for expected value?

[image: Symbol that I'm looking for.]

Comment: Are you looking for `\mathbf{E}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I believe your question is covered by [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26/11002).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps you need

```
\mathbf{E}.
```

Does this solve?

```
 \documentclass{article}  
 \begin{document}
 \[ \mathbf{E}(\xi)=\int_Z\xi d\rho \]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!